# MySQL Index not working ( Use Case specific scenario)

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

So far following is my scenario :

**Parameters** controlled by user: (These parameters are controlled by a dashboard but for testing purposes I have created sql parameters in order to change their values)

```
    SET @device_param := "all devices";
    SET @date_param_start_bar_chart := '2016-09-01';
    SET @date_param_end_bar_chart := '2016-09-19';
    SET @country_param := "US";
    SET @channel_param := "all channels";
```

**Query** that runs  at the back-end

```
SELECT 
  country_code,
  channel_report_tag,
  SUM(count_more_then_30_min_play) AS '>30 minutes',
  SUM(count_15_30_min_play) AS '15-30 Minutes',
  SUM(count_0_15_min_play) AS '0-15 Minutes' 
FROM
  channel_play_times_cleaned 
WHERE IFNULL(country_code, '') = 
  CASE
    WHEN @country_param = "all countries" 
    THEN IFNULL(country_code, '') 
    ELSE @country_param 
  END 
  AND IFNULL(channel_report_tag, '') = 
  CASE
    WHEN @channel_param = "all channels" 
    THEN IFNULL(channel_report_tag, '') 
    ELSE @channel_param 
  END 
  AND iFnull(device_report_tag, '') = 
  CASE
    WHEN @device_param = "all devices" 
    THEN iFnull(device_report_tag, '') 
    ELSE @device_param 
  END 
  AND playing_date BETWEEN @date_param_start_bar_chart 
  AND @date_param_end_bar_chart 
GROUP BY channel_report_tag 
ORDER BY SUM(count_more_then_30_min_play) DESC 
limit 10 ;
```

The **index** that I have applied is

```
CREATE INDEX my_index 
ON channel_play_times_cleaned (
  country_code,
  channel_report_tag,
  device_report_tag,
  playing_date,
  channel_report_tag
)
```

I have followed this link : [My SQL Index Cook-Book Guide](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php) to create my index.

However the **EXPLAIN** keyword while executing the above query tells me that there is no index used.

[image]

**I want to what am I doing wrong over here ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You use functions and case expression in the first 3 where condition. Simple field index cannot be used to speed up such look ups.
2. MySQL could potentially use an index for the `playing_date` criteria, but that field is not the leftmost in the cited index, therefore the cited index is not suitable for that either.

If I were you, I would remove the logic from the where criteria and moved that into the application layer by constructing such an sql statement that has the case conditions resolved and emits only the necessary sql.

Comment: You are correct. The problem is that I'm using pentaho community dashboard editor which only allows me to provide sql query as a data source hence I'm forced to apply this logic on database level. Is there any other method by which I can achieve the same functionality ?

Comment: I do not see any way to use indexes for the criteria with the case expressions, not even with indexed generated columns. You may declare an index to support the date range filter and the group by clause, so MySQL could use an index for at least some of the criteria.

Comment: +1 @Shadow but I think there is a way to express the predicate in terms the optimizer can work with, and use appropriate indexes (though I think more than just the one index will be called for, so an appropriate one can be selected during the planning stage).

Answer (score 1):

Your `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause are forcing full table scans.  Clearly, they have to go... but how?

You have to think like the optimizer and remember that its job is to avoid as much work as possible.

Consider this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE first_name LIKE '%a%';
```

Every row must be read to find all first_name values containing the letter 'a'.  Very slow.

Now, this one:

```
SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE first_name LIKE '%a%'
   AND 2 < 1;
```

For each row, you're asking the server to check the first_name again and to include only rows where 2 is a smaller number than 1.

Is it slow, or fast?

It's very fast, because the optimizer detects an `Impossible WHERE`.  There is no point in scanning the rows because 2 < 1 is always false.

Now, use this logic to tell the optimizer what you *really* want:

Not this:

```
  WHERE IFNULL(country_code, '') = 
   CASE
     WHEN @country_param = "all countries" 
     THEN IFNULL(country_code, '') 
     ELSE @country_param 
   END 
  AND
```

But this:

```
 WHERE
  (
    (
      @country_param = "all countries" 
    )
    OR
    (
      @country_param != "all countries"
      AND
      country_code = @country_param
    )
  )
  AND ...
```

The difference should be stark.  If @country_param = "all countries" the second test is not needed, and otherwise, only the rows with the matching country are needed and this portion of the `WHERE` clause is false by definition for all other rows, allowing an index on country_param to be used.

One or the other of these OR'ed expressions is *always* false, and that one will be optimized away, early -- never evaluated for each row.  The expression `@country_param != "all countries"` should be treated no differently than the expression `2 < 1` or `2 > 1`.  It is not going to change its truthiness based on the data in the rows, so it only needs to be evaluated once, at the beginning.

Repeat for the other `CASE`.  You should almost never pass columns as arguments to functions in the `WHERE` clause because the optimizer can't "look backwards through" functions and form an intelligent query plan.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have explained why your query is slow.  I will explain what you *should* do.

Write code to "construct" the query.  It would either leave out the test for `country_code` if the user said "all countries", or it add in `AND country_code = "US"`.  No @variables, no CASE, etc.

Then, one 5-column index won't work except for a few cases.  Instead, get a feel for what users are asking for, then build a few 2-column indexes to cover the popular cases.

Comment: That would of course be an even better solution.  I assumed from comments that this is an environment that can't build dynamic queries.